# How would I convert from UTC to EST based on the time value that's currently present in the column?

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging

I'd like to convert the time on both `start` and `end` columns from UTC to EST using SQL.  I found the below query somewhere on the web after hours of searching for a way to do this but to no avail (the query below's incorrect).

Is there a clean way to convert from UTC to EST based on the date of the field?

`start` column has the current value of `2019-06-01 05:00:00`

`end` column has the current value of `2019-06-30 04:00:00`

I'd like these to be in EST timezone.

Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET start = from_tz(to_timestamp('2009-11-17 18:40:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC'), end = from_tz(to_timestamp('2009-11-17 18:40:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') 
AT TIME zone 'America/New_York'
WHERE id = 3;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used above.)

Comment: @jarlh yeah, that's true.  I kind of didn't know what else to use.  I'm using regular MySQL.

Comment: When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant, so the dbms tag is essential.

Comment: @jarlh yeah you have a point, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn.

Comment: when you say EST, do you mean Eastern Time (which is EST or EDT depending on time of year)?  and specifically Eastern Time using US dst rules?

Comment: are you wanting your query to return eastern time values?  or you want to actually change your data to eastern time?  if the latter, please reconsider; times should always be stored in utc.  once you convert them, there's no way to convert back, since 1 hour a year is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVER_TZ

you can use '+00:00' so the server hasn't to look it up, which will save time, like ysth explained in the comment

> ```
> SELECT
>   CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 2:00:00','UTC','America/New_York') AS time1,
>   CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 3:00:00','UTC','America/New_York') AS time2;
> ```
>
> ```
> time1               | time2              
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 2007-03-10 21:00:00 | 2007-03-10 22:00:00
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE my_table
> SET start = CONVERT_TZ('2009-11-17 18:40:05','UTC','America/New_York')
>     , end = CONVERT_TZ('2009-11-17 18:40:05','UTC','America/New_York') 
>
> WHERE id = 3;
> ```
>
> ```
> Table 'db_477873842.my_table' doesn't exist
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 2:00:00','+00:00','America/New_York') AS time1,
>   CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 3:00:00','+00:00','America/New_York') AS time2;
> ```
>
> ```
> time1               | time2              
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 2007-03-10 21:00:00 | 2007-03-10 22:00:00
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE my_table
> SET start = CONVERT_TZ('2009-11-17 18:40:05','+00:00','America/New_York')
>     , end = CONVERT_TZ('2009-11-17 18:40:05','+00:00','America/New_York') 
>
> WHERE id = 3;
> ```
>
> ```
> Table 'db_477873842.my_table' doesn't exist
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d3aae805d46ef7c26c79db8ac35ba44)*

Comment: use `'+00:00'` for UTC, to avoid the server having to look up the dst rules for the UTC "timezone" (which don't exist).